# How to make a pull request using Git (if possible or using another software) and run in batch file?

Tags: git, github, batch-file

```
@echo off
:TOP
cd "D:\CA"
git stage .
git commit -m "Auto Commit"
git push origin test
goto :TOP
```

This auto commits and pushes to my test branch and I also have a main branch and I want when there is a difference between the test and main branches to send a pull request to the main branch that I can view on the pull requests of the repo and choose to add it or not now since its looping.

I want to make sure that we don't send the same pull request many times title can be anything. I just want to do that and I don't know if this is possible with Git. If not, is there any software that it would be possible with, with an easy implementation to this code?

Comment: What you want to do seems strange (or even wrong!) but have a look at https://cli.github.com/ especially `gh pr create`  https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create

Comment: And in your loop, you want to sleep so that the commands are not run too often...

Comment: Also `cd /d` looks like a good idea (see `cd /?`). Obvioulsy, not your problem here, but might save you from trouble in the future.